# Passing Stripe Webhooks to development environment using Stripe CLI

Tags: docker, stripe-payments

I am trying to forward stripe webhooks to my local development environment running on Docker. I use the following command but I get an error saying no such host.

My server webhook needs to be accessed by domain name and not IP address / docker service name as it is linked to a DNS subdomain

```
docker run --rm -it --net=app-network stripe/stripe-cli listen --forward-to https://www.domain.local/webhookstatus --skip-verify --api-key sk_test_xxx
```

I think I may need to pass in the DNS config directly to the Stripe container.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Your domain may be a host name or alias inside docker network. Using docker-compose or not ensure that Stripe container shares the same network.